# Why ln does not show ../..?

Tags: linux, bash

```
$ mkdir testln && cd testln
$ echo 123 > source
$ mkdir -p aa/bb/cc/dd
$ ln -s source aa/bb/cc/dd/dest
$ ll aa/bb/cc/dd/
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sato sato 6  1 12 15:08 dest -> source
$ cat aa/bb/cc/dd/dest
cat: aa/bb/cc/dd/dest: No such file or directory
$ cd aa/bb/cc/dd/
$ ll
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sato sato 6  1 12 15:08 dest -> source
$ ln -s ../../../../source dest2
$ ll
total 16
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sato sato  6  1 12 15:08 dest -> source
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sato sato 18  1 12 15:10 dest2 -> ../../../../source
```

As you can see, I did two `ln`

the first one only show `dest -> source` instead of `dest -> ../../../../source`, and show `No such file or directory`, why is that?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: @PaulR I disagree with that.

Comment: @hek2mgl: any reason ? It just seems to be a question about symbolic links in *nix - I see no code or any programming-related aspect to the question ?

Comment: Where do you draw the border? I mean understanding how a symbolic link works is required for system programming, in this case for a shell script. Would you also say a question like "How to store a file in binary mode?" is off-topic? Probably not the best example, I admit. What I want to say is that the sites SO, UNIX and superuser are somewhat related. If you want to move it, then I would say http://unix.stackexchange.com/ (where it is a duplicate ;) ) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
ln -s ../../../../source aa/bb/cc/dd/dest
```

The `source` path must be relative to `dest`. Check [`man ln`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html)

Comment: Yeah, it works!

Comment: but it needs to calculate `../../`, for example, I have `aa/bb/cc/dd/dest` and `aa/bb/dest`  and `aa/bb/cc/dest`, which need to link to source, so  I have to change `../../../../source` every time I `ln`, any quick fix?

Comment: No. The link target must be relative to the destination. The destination must always be in the level of hierarchy when using relative targets

Comment: I meant in the *same* level of hierarchy. That was a typo.